# How do you get $bot->userStorage()->delete() to work in botman?

Tags: php, php-7.3, botman

Considering the code below:

```
$botman->hears('show-delete', function($bot) {
    $stuff = $bot->userStorage()->all();
    $bot->reply(serialize($stuff)); // first dump
    $bot->userStorage()->delete();
    $stuff = $bot->userStorage()->all();
    $bot->reply(serialize($stuff)); // shows exactly same stuff as first dump
});
```

If the [manual](https://botman.io/2.0/storing-information#delete-storage) and [this reply](https://github.com/botman/botman/issues/473) are correct, the second reply statement should be an empty object but its exactly the same. In other words, the delete method has no effect.

What could be wrong?